# Convert datetime to MM yyyy, dd using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to change the date format to `MM:yyyy:dd` (October 2018, 24), I've tried every method I know, but it's not working... here is my code(one of many method I got online):

```
var data = (from o in db.tbPATxns
                            join p in db.providers on o.providerid equals p.providertin
                            join a in db.Endorsements on o.panumber equals a.panumber
                            join b in db.members on o.IID equals b.legacycode
                            join c in db.proceduredatas on a.proccode equals c.procedurecode
                            where c.proceduredesc.ToLower().Contains("admission")
                            select new
                            {
                                o.panumber,
                                b.legacycode,
                                b.lastname,
                                b.firstname,
                                b.phone1,
                                p.providername,
                                a.txndate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
                            });

                RadGrid1.DataSource = data.ToList();
                RadGrid1.DataBind();
```

Please help me out.

Comment: *"I've tried every method I know"* - could you show at least one of your attempt please?

Comment: And what does "not working" mean? Any exception? Unexpected results?

Comment: @Sinatr: well, that's why he said _"tried every method i  know"_ (emphasis on last two words)

Comment: "change the date format", Chaging the format in database? There is no Format on a `DateTime`. Or Displaying the date in the specified format?

Comment: Linq won´t help you at all to convert data. Just write what you would do *without* linq, then put this into a linq-expression.

Comment: try `a.txndate.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd")` Please note that this will return the month name according to the current culture - so you might get `octubre` for Spanish or `Oktober` for German.

Comment: tried it before, but not working @Zohar

Comment: Try assigning it to a string variable then using it. `string x = a.txndate.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd");`

Comment: also tried it before, still not working @Clarke

Comment: try to name the property of the Anonymous type . `new { property1 = .., property2 = ..}`

Comment: "not working" doesn't mean anything. Do you get errors? If so, what errors do you get? What is the type of `txndate`? (I was assuming `DateTime` but I might be wrong).

Comment: its a datetime  and the the error is _No Overloads for method toString() takes 1 arguments_ @Zohar

Comment: @HimBromBeere example please

Comment: You need to make your question more clear: what is the input, what is the desired output. What is the current output. Any errors? etc.

Comment: If that is the error it's not a DateTime. The DateTime struct has an overload of the ToString method that takes a string as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

The letters "MM" will return only the month number. If you want to show the month name you need to use something like this:

```
DateTime.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I think in your code is:

```
a.txndate.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will return an string with the format you want

---

Edit: if you want to change de language you just need to change the IFormatProvider (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: it isn't working, returning errors

Comment: Which errors are returning?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.ToString(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) to specify the `DateTime` format.

> `MMMM`  Full month name (e.g. December)
>   `yyyy`  Year, (e.g. 2015)
>   `dd`    Represents the day of the month as a number from 01 through 31.

```
var listDate = new List<DateTime>();
listDate.Add(new DateTime(1980, 5, 5));
listDate.Add(new DateTime(1982, 10, 20));
listDate.Add(new DateTime(1984, 1, 4));
listDate.Add(new DateTime(1979, 6, 19));

var result = listDate.Select(x => new { property1 = x.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd"), property2 = x });

foreach (var d in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.property1);
}
```

Result:

```
mai 1980, 05
octobre 1982, 20
janvier 1984, 04
juin 1979, 19
```