# Convert DateTime format to MMMM yyyy, dd using SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to change the date format to MM:yyyy:dd (October 2018, 24), I've tried every method I know, but it's not working... here is my code(one of many method I got online):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

SQLDataManager sql = new SQLDataManager(false);
string query = "SELECT * FROM member_case_management where panumber like '%'+ @value +'%'";

sql.AddParamAndValue("@value", searchvalue);

dt = sql.GetDataset(query, CommandType.Text).Tables[0];

var response = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable() 
                select new { a = r.Field<string>("a"), 
                              b = r.Field<DateTime>("b").ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd") }
               ).ToList();

return dt;
```

the query will get all the data in the database, but I want the date to come in MMMM yyyy, dd for, but the result am getting is

```
        panumber: 213456
        admissiondate: 6/21/2018 4:40:15 PM
        enrolleefeedback: satisfactory 
        enrolleestatus: treatment satisfactory
        statusdetails: planned discharge
        dischargedate: 6/21/2018 4:40:15 PM
        totaladmissiondays: 83days
        txndate: 6/21/2018 4:40:15 PM
        insuredid: 3431528465
        comments: satisfactory
```

Comment: is this query returning one column only?

Comment: What is the column type for the date?  If it's a date type then you've got a `DateTime` which doesn't have a format and in that case you have to tell the DataTable how to format that column.  If by some horrible chance the date is in your DB as a string then you'll have to parse it to a date first.

Comment: how you used this `method`?

Comment: no, its returning many columns, but datetime is in 3 of the columns @Eray

Comment: You could and should have added this as clarification to your previous question.

Comment: @ershoaib, I added the code you told me after the **dt = sql.GetDataset(query, CommandType.Text).Tables[0];**

Comment: Which part of the code snippet you posted is attempting to format the date the way you want?   I'm not seeing it somehow.

Comment: @tab, sorry forgot to add it, check again

Comment: Is this part of a wider issue you're having? I noticed you've posted some date queries relating to LINQ recently; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971939/convert-datetime-to-mm-yyyy-dd-using-lambda-espression and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988274/convert-datetime-format-to-mmmm-yyyy-dd-using-lambda-espression

Comment: @d219 I've complete the work for my client, but he insist the date format should be that format, already solve the linq issue, its remaining the sql query part. Am suppose to submit this work today

Comment: @EmmanuelIkechukwu, could u plz add which columns did u received from sql query in `dt` and how you can used the above method?

Comment: @ershoaib, I've done it sir, I've added all the columns and the output

Comment: @EmmanuelIkechukwu, i posted my answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your function return `dt`.

```
public DataTable YourMethodName()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SQLDataManager sql = new SQLDataManager(false);
            string query = "SELECT * FROM member_case_management where panumber like '%'+ @value +'%'";

    sql.AddParamAndValue("@value", searchvalue);

    dt = sql.GetDataset(query, CommandType.Text).Tables[0];

    return dt;
}
```

2) Then you can access your `dt` and format all those `date` columns to your desired format like.

```
DataTable dt = YourMethodName();

var response = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                select new
                {
                     panumber = r.Field<int>("panumber"),
                     //Do this for all remaing columns
                     admissiondate = r.Field<DateTime?>("admissiondate")?.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd"),
                     dischargedate = r.Field<DateTime?>("dischargedate")?.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd"),
                     txndate = r.Field<DateTime?>("txndate")?.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd"),
                     //Do this for all remaing columns
                     comments = r.Field<string>("comments")
                }
               ).ToList();
```

3) You can use above `response` as `DataSource` like.

```
Grid1.DataSource = response.ToList();
Grid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: sir, its returning an error **Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type**

Comment: @EmmanuelIkechukwu, answer updated... kindly noticed all  **Question mark (?)**

Comment: @EmmanuelIkechukwu, glad to hear, mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Comment: Thank you sir once again

Comment: @EmmanuelIkechukwu, sorry friend,  stackoverfolw doesn't allow for mutual or personal connection otherwise our account will be blocked by moderators.

Comment: @EmmanuelIkechukwu, I'll try to find an authentic way of stackoverflow to how u can connect with me, if i found then I'll ping you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FORMAT` to customize the output of a date time:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMMM yyyy, dd')
-- Returns: October 2018, 25
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

You don't mention the column in your query is the source date. Assuming the column was named "DateColumn", you could adjust your query like this:

```
string query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(DateColumn, 'MMMM:yyyy:dd') AS FormattedDate FROM member_case_management where panumber like '%'+ @value +'%'";
```

**UPDATE ON PERFORMANCE**

As mentioned in the comments, for large result sets, `FORMAT` can be very slow. If that does affect you, here is a more manual approach (again assuming "DateColumn" as the name of your column):

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, DateColumn) + ' '
    + CONVERT(CHAR(4), YEAR(DateColumn)) + ', '
    + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DAY(DateColumn)), 2) AS Formatted
```

I just ran a quick performance comparison on just over 4MM records, and this performed about 93% faster than the `FORMAT` equivalent.

Comment: Two items.   1) actual format should be 'MMMM yyyy, dd'  ... not sure if the semicolons are demonstrative.   2)  Should mention that format() has some great features, but should be used sparingly because it is not known to be a performer.   Other than that  +1

Comment: Thanks, i updated for "MMMM yyyy, dd" (I got caught up on first line that "MM:yyyy:dd" in OP). Agree with #2, but FORMAT is cleaner than alternatives to format manually. If data set is very large, agree completely it is worth other approaches.

Comment: Added update to show manual example for same output. I knew `FORMAT` could be slow, but I wasn't expecting that slow.  This was a great read: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but